# I want to make an application where the admin can read/create/update all users (Asp.Net Core 6.0 MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have managed to make a 'Read', but the Update and Delete do not work. My login/register system is made by scaffolding. Here is what I get after trying to update/delete.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3FmW.png)

I have been busy all day yesterday, but couldn't come to a solution. If anyone would like to help. That would be nice :D

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5rDC.png)

This is what I have in my Index, I send the Id of the account, but since it is really not an int ID, but a string. It doesn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG7gM.png)

Comment: I think, you are supposed to give some more details, as far as I see, you get 404 error, so you can check if your action methods have for example [HttpGet("id")] on top of them.

Comment: Please do not post code and error messages as images - copy-paste and format them as text instead. See also https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode